# How to get font sizes of recognized text to Recognize Name using font size on the Business Card form the Recognized text using OCR: iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, ocr, nsregularexpression

I have implemented **Business Card Reader App for iPhone** using **OCR** by

[Tesseract library](http://tinsuke.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-compile-and-use-tesseract-3-01-on-ios-sdk-5/)  its a  open source library. Api

**The main agenda is when the text is recognized from the business card. I need to pass the Name and Email address and Phone numer to the corresponding fields.**

i did it for **email address and phone numbers using their formats of expressions.**

but in case of *NAME some other texts having the same formats*, so we can pick it up using font size

**`How to get font sizes of recognized text to Recognize Name using font size on the Business Card form the Recognized text using OCR...?`**

Answer (score 4):

Just try this -

```
UIFont *font = totalLabel.font;
CGFloat maxHeight = font.lineHeight * totalLabel.numberOfLines;
CGFloat maxWidth = totalLabel.frame.size.width;
CGSize size = [totalLabel.text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:(CGSize){maxWidth, maxHeight} lineBreakMode:totalLabel.lineBreakMode];
```

Comment: Thankx JULAY i printeted all the recognized text in a text view, it hase smae font for all. but i need to find out the font of the second highest font in the bussiness card text.